# Error "Object variable or With block variable not set"

Tags: excel, vba

I'm running the below code as part of a larger sub:

```
Dim rEmp As Range
Dim rDate As Range
Set sDate = Sheet1.Range("C1")
Set rEmp = Sheet2.Range("A:A").Find(what:=rDate, lookat:=xlWhole)
If Not rDate Is Nothing Then
    If Cells(rEmp.Row, "B") = vbNullString Then
        Selection.Copy Cells(rEmp.Row, "B")
    Else
        If MsgBox("Do you want to overwrite the value ", _
        vbQuestion + vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
        Worksheets("PrimQ").Range("A1:AU1").Copy Cells(rEmp.Row, "B")
        End If
    End If
Else
    Rows("3:3").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Sheet2.Range("A3").Value = Sheet1.Range("C1").Value
    Range("A3").Select
    Worksheets("PrimQ").Range("A1:AU1").Copy Destination:=Sheet2.Range("B3")
End If
```

The error

> Object variable or With block variable not set

is showing on:

```
If Cells(rEmp.Row, "B") = vbNullString Then
```

I can't work out what the problem is though.

Comment: rdate is not found and rEmp is nothing

Comment: I think it should be `If Not rEmp Is Nothing`?

Comment: Also you have not defined `rDate`. Your other line refers to `sDate`.

Comment: Ah, yep. That was it, on both counts actually. Mistype on the sDate but main thing was the if not rEmp. Cheers for the help.